# How to turn off SSL in Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I had letsencrypt cert installed before , but then it got expired and now i am not able to renew it .

so I am trying to switch off the SSL i have removed the code related with SSL but still the url is redirecting to `https`.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80  ipv6only=on;


    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name domain.in www.domain.in;


    ssl off;

    #charset utf-8;
        #include h5bp/basic.conf;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 168h;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
     location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        client_max_body_size 1024M;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}
```

Any Idea how to fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any HSTS headers when you had https enabled?

Comment: @AnandBhat what is that?

Comment: HSTS / Strict-Transport-Security informs the browser that the site should always be access with HTTPS. HSTS basically tells a browser, "hey, from now on, only access me with HTTPS" for however long the max-age the header was set for. There is a good [writeup here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hsts-the-missing-link-in-tls/).

Comment: @vcsjones can you tell me how i can switch it off, because other servers are working fine now , only this one particular domain is redirecting to htttps

Comment: The point is once a browser thinks "This domain is HSTS enabled" you can't. The browser will always try to use HTTPS. The only way to fix it is to get HTTPS enabled.

HSTS I don't *think* is enabled by default with Let's Encrypt. You should check to see if it was enabled.

Comment: @vcsjones so what shoud I do now , The website is down , and letsencrypt is not working on my server when i try to install it syas can find letsencrypt or letsencrypt-auto anything

Comment: I remeber last time i just ran `letsencrypt renew ` to refresh the certificate

Comment: Did you had a 301 redirect or a 302? The first one is permanent while the other is not. Permanent means that the browser already knows it has to redirect and will not ask the server, i.e. removing the redirect at the server will not help.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich how can i find it  ?

Comment: Take a fresh browser  (or browser profil) which never visited the site before or clear the cache of the browser. If it works then it was a 301. Or have a look at the requests send by the browser in the developer tools.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich my domain iclock.in sorry i am not able to find that out

Comment: @user2671011: currently there is no redirect from this domain to https. So I guess that you had a 301 redirect which is still active in the browsers. You need to clear the cache of every browser in this case :(. It might also be that you had HSTS as others suggested which is even harder to get rid off.

Comment: If it isn't loading in Google Chrome for you, you can go to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and enter your domain name to see if there is an entry for your domain under "Query". If `dynamic_sts_domain` has a value, then your domain was HSTS enabled.

Comment: @vcsjones thanks for the advice yes its working now , And no it was not added inside HSTS so I believe it was my browser cache once i cleared that it works fine now

Comment: @SteffenUllrich and thanks for your help

Comment: Surely the proper solution is to figure out how to get HTTPS back up for you. Browsers will become increasingly irate about unencrypted sites going forward; if you care at all about your users' experience, you want to stay on HTTPS.-